# Can WSARecv() return data immediately?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, iocp

When calling `WSARecv()`, is it possible that the data will be returned immediately without going through the completion port phase. In the `WSARecv()` documentation, it says for the `lpNumberOfBytesRecvd` parameter:

> A pointer to the number, in bytes, of data received by this call if
>   the receive operation completes immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and this is not unusual. Remember that data arrives in IP packets whose boundaries in general do not align with your reads. If your `WSARecv` call requests data from packets that the OS already holds, there's no point to delay and Windows probably will return it immediately.

Comment: However, the event is still queued and you don't have to code a special path for immediate completion if you don't want to

Comment: @mnunberg You mean even if the data were read immediately, a completion packet would still be placed in the completion port?

Comment: Yes. Let me find the reference to this... Actually, I'm no longer sure. The "Documentation" hints that one or the other are mutually exclusive (i.e. the dwNBytes should be NULL if lpOVERLAPPED is not NULL, but I'm not sure how correct that documentation is).

Comment: It "Seems to work" here. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908435/wsasend-wsarecv-completion-routines-scheduling-questions

Comment: You can turn off completion port dispatch on successful I/O calls by setting `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` using `SetFileCompletionNotificationModes()` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @LenHolgate: That seems to be file (disk) specific and not relevant to WSARecv?

Comment: What makes you think that? It's very relevant to sockets and works really well at reducing unnecessary context switches. I've been using it for years.

Comment: @LenHolgate: Well, the repeated use of "file" in the article, the reference to Installable File Systems, and the list of supported technologies (all file systems).

Comment: I guess it just depends if you have a 'unixy' view of what a file handle can represent or not :) - anyway it's mentioned here in relation to high performance sockets: http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2008/06/26/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-iii.aspx

Answer (score 4):

When an overlapped `WSARecv()` completes with `IO_PENDING` or `SUCCESS` a completion packet is queued to the IOCP see [this MSDN article for details](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q192800).

With Vista or later you can change this by calling [`SetFileCompletionNotificationModes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the socket and passing `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` (note you can read File as Socket in the docs, the concept of a file handle translates directly to a socket).

If you DO enable completion port skipping then when a `WSARecv()` returns immediately with data (i.e. a `SUCCESS` return rather than an `IO_PENDING` return) then you MUST handle it directly at the `WSARecv()` call site as you WILL NOT get a completion packet.

Note that enabling "skip completion port" processing is great for reducing context switching, but you DO now need to handle completions either directly or in your normal completion handler.